# Grab google reviews and create a review form that works with Google API

Tags: google-api, zapier, webflow

Essentially, I want to find out if this idea can be executed using Google API. So I am using Zapier and Webflow for my work. I would like to know if it is possible to pull reviews from Google My Business to place on a customers website and also create a custom form that allows users to fill the form in to upload their reviews directly to Google My Business and website via the Google API.

**Design Concept:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done whenever new review on your google page publish zapier will push it into your webflow cms collection then you can use it in any way or you can write custom code to pick latest reviews using google api